# JSON and CURL encoding

Tags: php, json, android-studio, curl

I have a curl page that output in json format but I can't get json reading from android correctly. I want Json format with just an array only not object and array together. Check the output at the bottom for example. I want to write a php code that encode json that matches below. How would i do that? Thanks.

**PHP FILE:**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ .  '/vendor/mashape/unirest-php/src/Unirest.php';


//$response = Unirest\Request::get("",
//  array(
//    "host" => "",
//    "key" => "
//  )
//);
//
//
//echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "json",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'),
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "host: ",
        "KEY: "
    ),
));


$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

$json = json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);


curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo stripslashes($response);
}

                        $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
                        fwrite($fp, stripslashes($response));
                        fclose($fp);
```

**ORIGINAL OUTPUT** FROM CURL:

```
{
    "quoteResponse": 
        {
        "result": [{
            "language": "en-US",
            "region": "US",
            "quoteType": "EQUITY",
            "quoteSourceName": "Nasdaq Real Time Price",
            "exchangeDataDelayedBy": 0,
            "regularMarketPrice": 30.69,
            "regularMarketTime": 1568404801,
            "regularMarketChange": 0.48000145,
            "regularMarketVolume": 45547913,
            "shortName": "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.",
            "priceHint": 2,
            "postMarketChangePercent": 0.0325846,
            "postMarketTime": 1568419190,
            "postMarketPrice": 30.7,
            "postMarketChange": 0.0100002,
            "regularMarketChangePercent": 1.5888827,
            "regularMarketPreviousClose": 30.21,
            "fullExchangeName": "NasdaqGS",
            "longName": "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.",
            "market": "us_market",
            "pageViews": {
                "shortTermTrend": "UP",
                "midTermTrend": "UP",
                "longTermTrend": "UP"
            },
            "marketState": "CLOSED",
            "exchange": "NMS",
            "sourceInterval": 15,
            "exchangeTimezoneName": "America/New_York",
            "exchangeTimezoneShortName": "EDT",
            "gmtOffSetMilliseconds": -14400000,
            "esgPopulated": false,
            "tradeable": true,
            "triggerable": true,
            "symbol": "AMD"
        }],
        "error": null
    }
}
```

THE **OUTPUT I WANT** IS THIS WITHOUT `quoteResponse` LIKE ABOVE OUTPUT. CHECK BELOW :

```
{
    "result": [{
        "language": "en-US",
        "region": "US",
        "quoteType": "EQUITY",
        "quoteSourceName": "Nasdaq Real Time Price",
        "regularMarketPrice": 30.69,
        "regularMarketTime": 1568404801,
        "regularMarketChange": 0.48000145,
        "regularMarketVolume": 45547913,
        "sourceInterval": 15,
        "exchangeTimezoneName": "America/New_York",
        "exchangeTimezoneShortName": "EDT",
        "pageViews": {
            "shortTermTrend": "UP",
            "midTermTrend": "UP",
            "longTermTrend": "UP"
        },
        "gmtOffSetMilliseconds": -14400000,
        "market": "us_market",
        "postMarketChangePercent": 0.0325846,
        "postMarketTime": 1568419190,
        "postMarketPrice": 30.7,
        "postMarketChange": 0.0100002,
        "regularMarketChangePercent": 1.5888827,
        "priceHint": 2,
        "shortName": "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.",
        "regularMarketPreviousClose": 30.21,
        "fullExchangeName": "NasdaqGS",
        "longName": "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.",
        "exchange": "NMS",
        "exchangeDataDelayedBy": 0,
        "esgPopulated": false,
        "tradeable": true,
        "triggerable": true,
        "marketState": "CLOSED",
        "symbol": "AMD"
    }],
    "error": null
}
```

Comment: JSON is not a valid transfer encoding (but `gzip` and `deflate` is), replace it with emptystring to get compressed transfers, ref https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode your JSON, get `quoteResponse` from it and encode it again.

```
$json = json_encode(json_decode($json)->quoteResponse);
```

Comment: that is what i was thinking..can u give me an example? thanks.

Comment: What kind of example, exactly?

Comment: NEVER MIND. YOU ARE AWSOME! THANKS!

Comment: i got another question. let say there are more object in json. for example, "1stobject:"
    "2ndObjsquoteResponse": 
        {
        "result": [{}].... How would i delete the 1st and 2nd object?

Comment: You can again decode your JSON and iterate through the array and save the data form this array to a new array except 1stobject, 2ndobject,.. etc. And, then simply encode that new array to JSON.